# RPM creation solve depencies

Tags: yum, rpm, rpm-spec

I have created a rpm on Centos 7 it needs rh-python36 and centos-release-scl-rh is required to be installed in advance, so the current sequence is :

```
sudo yum install -y centos-release-scl-rh
sudo yum -y  localinstall ~/my_rpm.rpm
```

I would like to automatically install centos-release-scl-rh,
I tried to add it to the 'Requires' but it didn't work as only if I install centos-release-scl-rh in advance rh-python36 is available/solved.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in one operation. `yum` first reads all the repository information; then installs packages.

The package `centos-release-scl-rh` is a new repository that will only be 'read' by `yum` in the next transaction.